# ServiceStack Dto can't have object[] but int[] is Ok?

Tags: protobuf-net, servicestack-bsd

Works:

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class ExcelData
{
    public int[] DataObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Don't work:

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class ExcelData
{
    public object[] DataObjects { get; set; }
}
```

My test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ProtoWithObjectArray()
{
   var ex = new ProtoBufServiceClient(baseUrl);
   var res = ex.Get(new SelectWorksheetRange());
}

[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class SelectWorksheetRange : IReturn<ExcelData>
{
}
```

I don't even see error, because test just finish at ex.Get without any information. How to debug this?

Comment: There are no assertions in the test method. Are you just breakpointing at "var res = ..."?

Comment: @Hans Yes, it seems that I can't transfer object via protobuf.

Comment: If you can ever avoid using plain old "object", then you should (locks being the exception).

Comment: @Hans after reading from Excel service I'm creating my own DTO (without object) and using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment on ServiceStack, but as far as protobuf-net is concerned, yes: "`int[]` good, `object[]` bad". The reason is that the protobuf wire format (as designed by Google) is very terse and includes precisely zero metadata: it expects both ends of any conversation to know *exactly* what they are exchanging at any point. With `int[]`, that is possible, and with `object[]` it simply isn't. There are some nasty ways of hacking around it, but they tend to be problematic (maintenance-wise) and inefficient.

Comment: Solution is to cast `object[]` as `byte[]` and transfer bytes? It is very simple thought.

Comment: @Tomasito that would only work if the data always actually is of the cast type. And if it is: it should be declared as such in the first place. Finally, correct me if I am wrong, but IIRC array variance only applies to arrays of reference types. Byte is not a reference type.

Comment: I'm writing service to share Excel worksheet data. This service is then used by another services and they will do casting from `object[]` to something meaningful. And all Excel interop functions returns objects. Now is OK when I put object[] into `MemoryStream`

Comment: @Tomasito at no point does one "put object[] into MemoryStream". A memory stream wraps a byte buffer: nothing more. Sure you can *serialize* to a memory-stream, but then you need to follow the rules of the chosen serilaizer. For this reason, it is not uncommon to use different DTO models with different serializers in a single application.